# why snapshot.data gives me "Object?", but it don't gives returning of future?

Tags: flutter

i want to learn flutter step by step, I created UI, now i wanted to create fake firebase, later i will implement real firebase and i will use cubit, and then bloc.

I found this error, and i don't know how to remove it:
"AsyncSnapshot<Object?> snapshot
The argument type 'Object?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'FirstListModel'."

this is my code before i whas trying to implement fake firebase, as im trying to do now:

```
itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    final oneElement = firstList[index];
                    return buildPlate(index,await oneElement);
                  },
```

this itemBuilder is inside "ReorderableListView". Now im going step further and im trying to implement my fakeFirebase:

```
itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return FutureBuilder(
                      future: fakeFirebase.getElement(index.toString()),
                      builder: (context, snapshot) {
                        if (snapshot.hasData) {
                          return buildPlate(index, snapshot.data);
                        } else {
                          return const CircularProgressIndicator();
                        }
                      },
                    );
                  },
```

in the code above i have error in "snapshot.data"

in order to have better understanding, it is my function from fakeFirebase:

```
  @override
  Future<FirstListModel> getElement(String? id) async {
    FirstListModel error = FirstListModel(text: "error", id: "404");
    if (id != null) {
      return firstList[int.parse(id)];
    }
    return error;
  }
```

and this is my model:

```
class FirstListModel {
  String text;
  String id;
  FirstListModel({
    required this.text,
    required this.id,
  });
}
```

this is begining of my "buildPlate":

```
Widget buildPlate(int index, FirstListModel oneElement) => ListTile(
```

if i need to post more of my code, fell free to ask, it is my own aplication, just to lear flutter

"firstList" is a list of models, it containes objects that will be added by the user, simulating firebase

Comment: Change `FutureBuilder` to `FutureBuilder<FirstListModel>`

Comment: sadly, it did not helped me, error is still on

Comment: And change `buildPlate(index, snapshot.data)` to `buildPlate(index, snapshot.data!)` this will tell the buildPlate model the data from the snapshot is not null. You've checked it using `snapshot.hasData` so it should be safe.

Comment: it did resolve my problem, i needed to add "!", thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Define the type parameter for the future builder and cast the snapshot.data to non null by using the `!` operator

```dart
return FutureBuilder<FirstListModel>(
                      future: fakeFirebase.getElement(index.toString()),
                      builder: (context, snapshot) {
                        if (snapshot.hasData) {
                          return buildPlate(index, snapshot.data!);
                        } else {
                          return const CircularProgressIndicator();
                        }
                      },
                    );
```

Comment: it helped me! thank you!